# Own table in database or leaving a field empty?

Tags: mysql, database, attributes

In my project I have got the following tables:

- Event (id, title, date, user_id)
- Group (id, name, creator_id)
- User  (id, name, email,...)
- group_user (group_id, user_id)

In the application a user can have a personal event or a group can have a event that will be shared will all users in the group.

A user is able to create an event , then the events user_id is this users ID.

Now i would like to create an event within a group - so I need a relationship between the event and the group.

Should I create the attribute group_id in the event table and leave it empty if the event just belongs to a user and not to a group?
Or should I consider creating a new table like groupEvent which has got the attribute group_id.
Or should I create a pivot table group_event that contains the groupID and the eventID as attributes.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

One way I could think of is for you to get rid of the user_id foreign key in the Event table and instead have a User_Event table that maps users and events and a Group_Event table that maps groups and events. Not sure if this is the best design for your use case but this will avoid the need for two foreign keys in the Event table (of which one of them is NULL for every row).

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 separate table Group_Event(id,group-id,event-id) and User_Event(id,user-id,event-id).
Advantages of this method is that

- querying will be very easy.
- you can add multiple events for a user.
- you can add multiple events for a group.

But you should make sure that while adding an event to Group_Event
you should also add the same event to User_Event WHERE "User_Event.user-id" = "group_user.user_id" AND "group_user.group_id" = "Group_Event.group-id".